# Python SyntaxError when using end argument with print function

Tags: python

I don't know why i get the error because i have done exactly as the book says

```
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\Users\\expoperialed\\Desktop\\Pyt…'
>>> data = open('sketch.txt')
>>> print(data.readline(),end="")
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What python version are you using? `python --version`

Comment: Check your Python version.  Prior to Python 3, `print` wasn't a function, and this is the error 2.x gives if you try to call it like this.

Comment: what you REALLY want to do is to go download / install python 3.3 and never ever again use python 2. Also, upvoted the question :)

Comment: Yep, that's your problem then.  As the answers say, either upgrade your Python or find a book or online tutorial that covers the older version if you need to use the older version.

Comment: This syntax (`print('blabla', end='')`) is only available on Python 3.x

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Too opinion based. In my opinion, Python 2.7 is much better than Python 3.3.

Comment: Just false, there are too many bugs in unicode/str alone, if you haven't been bitten by these then good for you.

Comment: Lose the `end` argument and `print`, when called as function, would work on Python 2.x.

Answer (score 8):

Or, to use the print function like you want in Python 2:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
```

That will need to be at the top of your Python program though because of the way the `__future__` module works.

Answer (score 6):

I think your problem is that you are on Python 2.x and are using Python 3.x's syntax.  In Python 3.x, `print` is a built-in and can be used like that.  However, in 2.x, it is a keyword and cannot.  If you are on 2.x, do this:

```
print data.readline(),
```

One way to see which version of Python you are using is this:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info.major == 2:
    # We are running 2.x
elif sys.version_info.major == 3:
    # We are running 3.x
```

or, from the terminal:

```
$ python --version
```

The best way to fix this problem would probably be to upgrade to Python 3.x.  However, if you can't, then you might want to look at the `__future__` module.  It can make it so that you can use Python 3.x's `print` function in 2.x:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print("yes!")
yes!
>>> print("a", "b", sep=",")
a,b
>>>
```

Comment: added the missing , (that is what the end='') does

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're running the wrong python version. There's currently 2 versions of Python running around, 2 and 3. In Python 2, `print` is a statement so you should change your code too

```
 print data.readline(), # The trailing comma to stop the newline
```

while in 3 it's a function and should be used how your book shows.

It looks like your book is in Python 3 so you should upgrade your python (For a beginner there's no reason not to use Python 3)